# passing search params to another form using jquery autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, parameters

I am trying to pass a form parameter from an auto search field to another form and instead of the parameter, `#<Restaurant:0x4708a10>` is showing up.

Background info: 
I have two models: Restaurant and User. Restaurant has many users and users belong to restaurants. Restaurants are pre-populated in the database and when users want to sign up for an account, they have to first find the restaurant using an auto complete field. The url to do this is users/find_restaurant. Once they click submit, the form is posted to the results action of the users controller to check if users already exist for the restaurant. If users already exit, the person is redirected to the invitation action, if not, they are redirected to the new action. When users are taken to the new action, the restaurant_id column is showing `#<Restaurant:0x4708a10>`

Code is:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users

def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end

 end


class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :allow_user, :except => ['new', 'find_restaurant', 'results']
autocomplete :restaurant, :name, :display_value => :funky_method, :extra_data => [:id, :address, :city, :state, :zip_code]

  def find_restaurant
    @restaurants = Restaurant.search(params[:search])
    @users = @resturants.map(&:users).flatten.compact.uniq  
  end

  def results
     @restaurants = Restaurant.search(params[:search])
     @users = @restaurants.map(&:users).flatten.compact.uniq
      if @users.blank?
        redirect_to new_user_path
     else
        redirect_to restaurants_path(@school)
   end
end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @restaurants = Resturant.search(params[:search])
    @user.restaurant_id = @schools
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
        if @user.save
            redirect_to(:action => 'index')
        else
            render('new')
  end
  end
```

Form for find school is

```
<%= form_tag results_users_path, :method => 'get' do %>

<p>
    <%= autocomplete_field_tag :search, params[:search], autocomplete_restaurant_name_users_path, :value_method => :id %>
    <%= submit_tag "Next", :name => nil, :id => "submit" %>
</p>

<% end %>
```

Form for new is

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, :validate => true do |f| %>
<%= f.association :restaurant %>
<%= f.input :first_name %>
<%= f.input :last_name %>
<%= f.input :title %>
<%= f.input :email %>
<%= f.input :username %>
<%= f.input :password %>
<%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
<%= f.input :role %>
<%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are using f.association, so rails will convert it to an instance of Restaurant model. You can get the id from the object that you get.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I don't understand the response (I'm a newbie). Can you give me a hint about how to get the id from the object?